# `random.seed` doesn't work with generators

Tags: python, random, generator, random-seed

I have a function that generates a sequence of random integers using `random.randint`. I also include a seed parameter for reproducibility.

I noticed an odd behavior when I returned a generator object. Different calls with the same seed did not return the same result. However, when I returned a tuple instead of a generator, the results from different calls were the same.

Returning a generator.

```
In [2]: import random

In [3]: def rand_sequence(n, seed=None):
   ...:     if seed is not None:
   ...:         random.seed(seed)
   ...:     return (random.randint(0, n) for _ in range(n))
   ...:

In [4]: first = rand_sequence(10, seed=0)

In [5]: second = rand_sequence(10, seed=0)

In [6]: assert tuple(first) == tuple(second)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 assert tuple(first) == tuple(second)

AssertionError:
```

Returning a tuple

```
In [7]: def rand_sequence(n, seed=None):
   ...:     if seed is not None:
   ...:         random.seed(seed)
   ...:     return tuple(random.randint(0, n) for _ in range(n))
   ...:

In [8]: first = rand_sequence(10, seed=0)

In [9]: second = rand_sequence(10, seed=0)

In [10]: assert first == second

In [11]:
```

I guess it might have something to do with the control-flow mechanism of generators, but can't figure out how it plays out.

Edit:

What's even more confusing is when I used `yield` directly then the comparison checked out.

```
In [11]: def rand_sequence(n, seed=None):
    ...:     if seed is not None:
    ...:         random.seed(seed)
    ...:
    ...:     for _ in range(n):
    ...:         yield random.randint(0, n)
    ...:
    ...:

In [12]: first = rand_sequence(10, seed=0)

In [13]: second = rand_sequence(10, seed=0)

In [14]: assert tuple(first) == tuple(second)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator expression is evaluated later, lazily,
and it has side effects on the PRNG.

You will find it much easier to reason about your
algorithm if you first store PRNG outputs in a container,
such as a `tuple` or `list`.

Specifically, if your code produced

```
first = [f0, f1, f2, ..., f9]
second = [s0, s1, s2, ..., s9]
```

you are grappling with whether comparing equality of

```
f0 == s0
f1 == s1
...
f9 == s9
```

is "the same as" equality of

```
[f0, f1, ..., f9] == [s0, s1, ..., s9]
```

Perturbing the PRNG state in the middle of such
equality tests is going to cause you grief,
in the manner you have noted.
Simplify, store values in containers,
and you'll be happier.
Certainly the debugging situation will improve.

EDIT

I wouldn't go so far as @Carcigenicate's remark about

> ... and generators only evaluate as equal if they're literally the same generator.

We can certainly evaluate whether each successive
value generated by one matches what's generated by the other.
The core difficulty OP encountered is the
global PRNG state is shared across generators,
so order-of-evaluation matters.

```
>>> r1 = range(7)
>>> r2 = range(7)
>>> id(r1)
4396054832
>>> id(r2)
4396054880
>>> r1 == r2
True
```

Comment: I was wrong about the cause because I missed that they were forcing the generators before checking them. I'll point out though that `range` is not a generator, so it can have its values checked. And in theory you could create a custom generator that does store its values and support value comparisons, but I don't know of any such existing classes.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. However, when I used the `yield` statement instead of a generator expression, the equality check worked. Is this behavior of `yield` with regard to PRNG reliable? Or does the same global state problem still happen?

Comment: @HàmNghi I believe that's because in your first way, the seeding happens when both functions are called, and both function calls happen before elements are asked for. So you seed for 0 twice in a row, then request 20 elements (instead of seeding once, generating 10, then seeding again). When using a generator function though, the seeding doesn't happen until a element is requested (because the body doesn't run until a element is requested), and by the time that happens for `second`, `first`'s elements have already been generated.

Comment: Thanks again. It's clear to me now.